# How to view .evtx files on Linux (Windows Event Log)

Tags: windows, gratis, linux

I have a .evtx (Windows Event Log) file, and want to view it on Linux.

Requirements:

- Free
- Easy to install/run
- Works on Linux
- Command line tools are OK, GUIs are OK

Answer (score 6):

I found something that meets all your requirements, the only drawback is that the logs are a bit hard to parse by a human.

[python-evtx (GitHub repo)](https://github.com/williballenthin/python-evtx) is free/libre and is easy to install using `pip install python-evtx`. Use the command

```
python /usr/bin/evtx_dump.py some.evtx > some.xml
```

You'll end up with an XML with the logs content.

Answer (score 4):

On Debian and derived distributions, there is also [evtxexport](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/man1/evtxexport.1.html) :

> evtxexport is a utility to export items stored in a Windows XML
> EventViewer Log (EVTX) file

It is part of the "[libevtx](https://github.com/libyal/libevtx/blob/main/documentation/Windows%20XML%20Event%20Log%20(EVTX).asciidoc)-utils" package.

```
apt install libevtx-utils
```

(See also [my answer here](https://superuser.com/a/1608847/53547) with a few alternatives)

Answer (score 2):

I have found another utility for exporting evtx log to XML/JSON format:
[EVTX](https://github.com/omerbenamram/EVTX)

Self-described as "A cross-platform parser for the Windows XML EventLog format".

- Supports XML and JSON outputs
- Supports some basic recovery of missing records/chunks
- Claims to be much faster than python-evtx and golang-evtx
- License: Apache or MIT

Answer (score 1):

If you're open to an online tool, consider Gigasheet (http://gigasheet.co). It's a free tool that allows you to upload and work with EVTX files in a spreadsheet-like rows-and-columns interface.

A video detailing how this is done is here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X-vVSS7Llyw, and a blog post is here: https://www.gigasheet.co/post/online-evtx-parser-and-viewer. Gigasheet is built to work with files up to one billion rows.

Disclosure: I joined Gigasheet in January 2022.

Answer (score 1):

#### evtx (`evtx_dump`)

Use rust crate [`evtx`](https://crates.io/crates/evtx).  Assuming you have [rust installed](https://rustup.rs/) then run

```
cargo install evtx
```

It installs program `evtx_dump`.

```
$ evtx_dump.exe --help
EVTX Parser 0.8.1
Utility to parse EVTX files

USAGE:
    evtx_dump [OPTIONS] <INPUT>
```

#### Super Speedy Syslog Searcher (`s4`)

However, `evtx_dump` does not print the Events in a datetime sorted order, and can only print one `.evtx` file per run.

Program [*Super Speedy Syslog Searcher*](https://crates.io/crates/super-speedy-syslog-searcher) will process multiple `.evtx` files, and can print all Events in chronological order.

```
cargo install super_speedy_syslog_searcher
```

It installs program `s4`.

```
$ s4.exe C:\Windows\System32\winevt\Logs
```